# how extract entity with child entity to single view model with AutoMapper?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, automapper, viewmodel

I have the following entities:

```
public class ClassA
{
    public int Id{get;set;}
    public string Property1{get;set;}
    public string Property2{get;set;}        
    .
    .
    public string Property(n){get;set;}
    public ClassB Item{get;set;}
}

public class ClassB
{
    public int Id{get;set;}
    public string Property(n+1){get;set;}
    public string Property(n+2){get;set;}
    .
    .
    public string Property(n+m){get;set;}
}
```

And my ViewModel is :

```
public class MyViewModel
{
  public string Property1{get;set;}
  public string Property2{get;set;}
  .
  .
  public string Property(n+m){get;set;}
}
```

How can i mapping the class "ClassA" with child entity "ClassB" to "MyViewModel" with AutoMapper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option #1:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<ClassA, MyViewModel>();
Mapper.CreateMap<ClassB, MyViewModel>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Id, opt => opt.Ignore());

var vm = Mapper.Map<MyViewModel>(classA);
Mapper.Map<ClassB, MyViewModel>(classA.Item, vm);
```

Option #2:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<ClassA, MyViewModel>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Property(n+1), opt => opt.MapFrom(source => Item.Property(n+1)))
    .ForMember(...); //for each of ClassB property

var vm = Mapper.Map<MyViewModel>(classA);
```

Comment: Option #1 is my answer.This is exactly what I was looking for.thanks a lot